# Regex to remove all greater than and less than but not if "br" are between

Tags: regex

I want to remove all greater than and less than symbols. I do NOT want to remove the contents between those symbols and I do NOT want to remove br tags. Is there any way to do this? Keep in mind I have no idea how to use Regex.

This is what I have so far:

```
/[<>](?!b)/g
```

If I use that regex on this:

```
< >"' <<< <   <  <br> <aaa > >
```

Then I get this:

```
 "'       <br aaa
```

But I want this:

```
 "'       <br> aaa
```

Please help! (ノ´ロ`)ノ

EDIT: (To show the answer and use)
Function to print the contents of php "objects" for troubleshooting, etc.

```
function myPrint($myPrint, $returnAsString = FALSE){
    if($myPrint === FALSE){ $myPrint = "FALSE"; }
    if($myPrint === TRUE){ $myPrint = "TRUE"; }
    if($returnAsString === TRUE){
        return preg_replace(array("/\s/", "/<(?!br>)/", "/(?<!<br)>/"), array("&nbsp;","&#60;","&#62;"), nl2br(print_r($myPrint, true),false));
    }
    else{
        echo preg_replace(array("/\s/", "/<(?!br>)/", "/(?<!<br)>/"), array("&nbsp;","&#60;","&#62;"), nl2br(print_r($myPrint, true),false))."<br>";
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lets be honest, is this html? If it is I can give you a regex to remove all tags.

Comment: What language do you use? PHP? Python? Java?

Comment: Would be using this in a php doc @Parfait

Comment: @sln, that is exactly what I don't want to do.

Comment: [Don't use Regular Expressions to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/344638), because HTML is not a Regular Language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically it's easily done with a couple of assertions.

`<(?!br>)|(?<!<br)>`

Expanded

```
   <
   (?! br> )
|  
   (?<! <br )
   >
```

Comment: How does this work with <br /> or <br/> tags? https://regex101.com/r/oCX4aK/1